# Qual a melhor forma de retornar códigos de erros específicos de uma função?

Tags: algoritmo

Eu já ouvi falar que é uma boa prática retornar em funções apenas true ou false (1 ou 0), porém, caso eu crie uma função que verifica uma string, e eu queira saber quais os erros ocorreram nela, eu costumo retornar valores diferentes, por exemplo:

RETURN 1 - Se a string contém um número.

RETURN 2 - Se a string contém caracteres especiais.

RETURN 3 - Se a string contém alguma letra 'a'.

Então minha dúvida é, isso seria uma má prática de programação? E se é, qual outra forma eu faço para retornar determinado erro de uma função que verifica uma string (por exemplo).

OBS: Eu retorno valores diferentes para exibir um erro mais intuitivo e específico para o usuário.
Não quero apenas retornar 1 para dizer "Há um erro", quero dizer qual é o erro que aconteceu, por isso retorno 1, 2, 3....

Comment: Só é má prática aquilo que você faz que não atende aos requisitos do projeto.

Comment: Eu divirjo totalmente dessa 'boa' pratica. Uma função deve retornar aquilo que você precisa a partir daquilo que você pode informar.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso seja algo particular de cada programador e cada projeto, existem varias formas de se fazer um método de validação, por exemplo: tem quem prefira mostrar erros através de uma classe de exceptions, assim como tem gente que prefere fazer um método que retorna uma string.

O que eu recomendo pra você é criar um método que retorne uma variável do tipo boolean, porém possua uma variável out com a mensagem de erro; você não disse qual linguagem está trabalhando, mas acredito que a maioria de alto nível possua esta opção.

segue exemplo em c#:

```
public bool ValidaCampos (String minhaString, out string mensagemErro)
{
    mensagemErro = string.Empty;

    if (minhaString.Contains("a"))
        mensagemErro += "A string contém a letra A";

    ... demais validações

    return string.isNullOrEmpty(mensagemErro);
}
```